# Two connection strings for local and hosting server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-configuration

I would like to ask if there is a way to tell ASP.NET Core 2 to choose different connection strings.

It is quite annoying to keep changing the connection string in the `appsettings.json` file every time I publish my website to the hosting server..

I am using this code to get connection string.

```
 services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options => 
     options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:WebDataBase:ConnectionString"]));
```

Maybe there is an easy way but I am thinking of using an if statement in my Startup.cs:

```
if (local) {
    services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options => 
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:WebDataBase1:ConnectionString"]));
}
else {
    services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options => 
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:WebDataBase2:ConnectionString"]));
}
```

But how can I set this `local` variable whether the server is my local computer or a live hosting server?

```
"Data": {
  "WebDataBase1": {
    "ConnectionString": "Data Source=DatasoruceName;Initial Catalog=DBname;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=True;"
  },

  "WebDataBase2": {
    "ConnectionString": "Data Source=DatasoruceName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=True;"
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to separate environments. Here's one of the available methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: Additionally if you want to protect your connection strings take a peek here too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=windows

Comment: Exactly Baranyi, I am thinking maybe  I should use  IHostingEnvironment env in my ConfigureServices and just check env.IsDevelopment() or not... But i am not sure this will work or is there better one

Comment: It is not working... The ConfigureServices method must either be parameterless or take only one parameter of type IServiceCollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment specific configuration is not supposed to be specified within code. ASP.NET Core has a mechanism for that which allows you to swap out the configuration dependending on what environment you run on.

While developing your application, you usually run in the `Development` environment. When you are deploying your application for production, the `Production` environment is used by default. But if you have other environments, you can totally make up new names for those too and have specific configurations for them. That all is explained in the [Environments chapter of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

What environments allow you to do is create multiple `appsettings.json` files. The ASP.NET Core by default comes with two files: `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`.

The former is supposed to contain environment unspecific configuration; things that apply to all environments. The latter file contains development-specific configuration and for example adjusts the logging level so that you get more information during development. You can also use these files to specify a default connection string within `appsettings.json` and overwrite that for development within `appsettings.Development.json`.

Furthermore, the configuration file follows a very simple pattern: `appsettings.<Environment>.json`. So if you run in the `Production` environment, a file named `appsettings.Production.json` will be loaded if it exists. This mechanism allows you to configure all your environments differently without having to resort to detections within your code.

In addition, there is also the concept of *user secrets* during development. These are for development-specific configurations that do only apply to yourself but not for example to other members of your team. This is basically a per-machine configuration that allows you to overwrite both the `appsettings.json` and the `appsettings.Development.json`. This is described in the [user secrets chapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Best practice is to avoid connection strings altogether within configuration files though, since you want to avoid that people that happen to have access to your configuration files (for example through your source code) can know the passwords to your database. In that case you can use other mechanisms, for example [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#environment-variables-configuration-provider) that are local to the process.

---

In your case, where you are just using integrated security, and as such rely on the credentials of the current user, this is not that much of a problem. The only thing you are leaking is the database name. – So you can definitely start out with putting the connection strings into the appsettings files.

So for example, this is how you would configure your database context within your Startup’s `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebDataBase"));
```

Your `appsettings.Development.json` would look like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "WebDataBase": "Data Source=DatasourceName;Initial Catalog=DBname;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=True;"
  }
}
```

And your `appsettings.Production.json` would look like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "WebDataBase": "Data Source=DatasourceName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=True;"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help Poke. I just followed  Pro ASP.Net Core2 books connection string examples. You are right. I will change it..